# jQuery Autocomplete: dropdown does not show after first typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I use jQuery UI Autocomplete on my website. My problems:

- In Chrome and Firefox: When the user quickly enters a four letters term after loading the site and stops typing, the dropdown does not show immediately. Only after typing another letter, the dropdown then shows. From now on, the dropdown always shows, when the user changes the search term, so then there is no problem. When the user reloads the page and quickly types a new term and stops, again the dropdown does not show. When, after reloading the page, the user types the term very slow, the dropdown shows, then again there is no problem. How do I achieve that the dropdown will also show after "the first instance of typing"?
- In Internet Explorer, the dropdown never shows.

Here comes my code:

```
$('#my-search-input').on('keyup', function () {
            var characterLength = $(this).val().length;

            if ((characterLength > 2) || (characterLength == 0)) {
                typewatch(function () {
                    $('#my-search-input').autocomplete({
                        source: function (request, response) {
                            $.post(Routing.generate('my_path'), {
                                term: request.term
                            }, function (data) {
                                response(data)
                            }, 'json');
                        },
                        close: function (event, ui) {
                            loadResults();
                        }
                    });
                    loadResults();
                }, 500);
            }
        });

        var typewatch = (function () {
            var timer = 0;
            return function (callback, ms) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
            };
        })();
```

**UPDATE: JSFIDDLE**

Here comes a JS Fiddle which has similar code and contains the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/cd1kd08s/

When you type in "Alban" in order to find "Albania", the dropdown does not show right away. When you continue with typing the letter "i" (resulting in "Albani"), the dropdown shows.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use timer/keyup listeners for this stuff. I tried calling `autocomplete` plugin function on document load and it works well..

check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cd1kd08s/1/)